# Text Detection from textbook images and creating an identical text file

Tags: python, text, computer-vision, detection, google-cloud-vision

I'm building an app which can create a text file from the photo of a text-containing page(say a page of a textbook) such that the two are apparently identical. I used google-cloud-vision in PYTHON to detect the text and get the coordinates of the text within the image. Now these are the problems that I'm facing:

1. What library (or something) do I use to create a text file such that I can write text of different sizes(that is present within the input image)? -> High Priority
2. How do I determine if a word is written in BOLD or ITALICS or if it's underlined or determine its font, etc? 2nd High Priority
3. Say there is a TABLE containing a number of rows and columns; how do I detect a table and then write it inside the text file?

[here is a sample(simplest also) input image :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A92jx.jpg)

[here is a screenshot of the output (word) file:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fAFx.png)

Comment: The question is a rather unclear. Are you able to provide examples of inputs -> outputs that you are trying to achieve, what exactly do you mean by text sizes and what have you already tried (code wise). It sounds like you may need some machine learning, ```NLTK``` and possibly ```open-cv```

Comment: well basically if i have an image of a page of a textbook(which may contain font of different sizes or some text may be written in bold or be underlined etc. ), i want to get a text file(say a docx file) which looks exactly like the one in the image.

Comment: i found python-docx library; so gonna try this for now and see what happens.

Comment: Do you already have a method for extracting text from images already? Is the next step to determine formatting?

Comment: yes. i used google's cloud-vision api to extract the text. and now i am working on formatting(i.e copying the text into a text-file)

Comment: Post a sample of your input text then a sample of a desired output

Comment: please check my question. i have added the images. (also i manually typed the output-file to show you how it should be.) also some pages could contain fonts with different sizes; how do i account for that.